# how to locale field Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I used  gem Devise for authentication in my application . I want to change label text for below input
`<%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>`

but I can not find this field for standard renaming either in the service files or in the devise locale
how to locale this field ?

```
presently
check-box "Remember me"
```

_

```
need 
check-box "Запомнить меня"
```

Comment: In which language you need to change text ?

Comment: Russian language, but language doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en.yml

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: Email
        password: Password
        remember_me: Remember me
```

create new file for any other locale and add translated text for that language

de.yml

```
de:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: "email in de"
        password: "Password in de"
        remember_me: "Remember me in de"
```

You can read more about devise translation [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n)

Here is the very useful site for translations - https://www.localeapp.com/projects/377/translations/5250293?in_locale=5291